# roundcube dpkg-reconfigure failed

Tags: roundcube

I have no more idea
dpkg-reconfigure roundcube-core

failed with no reason. I reinstalled roundcube many times, no effect. Seems to be dpkg problem on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Here is some error

```
apt-get install --reinstall debconf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  php-sqlite3 php7.0-sqlite3 sqlite3
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 213 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/136 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'roundcube-core' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'roundcube-mysql' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 331508 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../debconf_1.5.58ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking debconf (1.5.58ubuntu1) over (1.5.58ubuntu1) ...
Setting up debconf (1.5.58ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
```

Comment: Could you provide the error message please?

Comment: absolute no error, dpkg-reconfigure roundcube-core just exits

Comment: first time, run. now, I don't know why I try for 2 hours to apt-get clean, dpkg clean and so on.. no result

Comment: please see debconf error in my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some struggle, solved.
In case anyone needs, here is the answer:

Clean first:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get --purge remove
```

Then try to reconfigure and force debug output, this is important:

sudo dpkg-reconfigure $(dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}'|grep "^roundcube"|tr '\n' ' ')

Hmm.. this shown the error that other way isn't shown at all!

```
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: roundcube-plugins is broken or not fully installed
```

Now, re-install that package... and works.

```
apt-get install roundcube-plugins
```